# What is Change Management in Sharepoint?

Tags: deployment

What is Change Management in Sharepoint? is there any best practices to follow? 
please let me know any Video tutorials that explains this concept. any useful Links are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad in a way that the `Change Management` systems can be way different depending on the functional domain they are being used.

There is a good, no code, solution provided [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19797.sharepoint-2013-build-a-change-management-request-without-code.aspx). Its a SP 2013 solution, involving InfoPath forms and List workflows. There are videos also embedded within the steps.